# Uploading mp3 files to server and build dynamic playlist from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mp3, playlist

For my school project, I need to build an mp3 player in JavaScript, which I have done. It works fine with predefined list of songs. So for now, I have a files stored in mp3 directory and table with information for every song, all that in plain html. My knowledge of MySql and PHP is on entry level, trying to improve every day.

But now, my teacher thinks that is to easy and now I need to do this:

- Build an MySql database with: id,artist,song,cover for every song
- Write a php code that would insert all that information in that database when I upload new song
- Only registered user could listen to all songs, so I need to built database for users and logging script.

All of this is no problem for me, but next part is a problem (for now, I hope so :) )

- When user logs in, he will see list of all songs from database with a check-box next to name, so he can choose songs that he wants to play. Basically, he will check those song that he want to listen and press submit button. After that, the script needs to send those data and create a table with that songs he checked.

I tried to find an answer or some kind of example, but without success. There is no restrictions and important thing about security issues, so don't bother with that. Just any working code would be good or direction how to it. Thanks :)

EDIT: The table now looks like this:

```
<ul id="playlist" class="hidden">
            <li song="Guns and Roses - Sweet child of mine.mp3" cover="guns.jpeg" ">Guns and Roses - Sweet child of mine.</li>
            <li song="Guns and Roses - Welcome to the Jungle.mp3" cover="guns.jpeg" ">Guns and Roses - Welcome to the Jungle</li>
            <li song="Michael Jackson - I Just Cant Stop Loving You.mp3" cover="mj.jpg" ">Michael Jackson - I Just Cant Stop Loving You</li>
            <li song="Michael Jackson - Thriller.mp3" cover="mj.jpg" ">Michael Jackson - Thriller</li>
            <li song="Joe Cocker - Up Where We Belong.mp3" cover="joe.jpg" ">Joe Cocker - Up Where We Belong</li>   
        </ul>
```

I need to makes it dynamic, to fill with data from database and to be able to play it.

Comment: Why do you want to persist the songs that a user wants to hear into a new table? For what do you want that information?

Comment: Maybe not a new table, just to fill the existing table in html (maybe with while function). Now I have static table with 5 songs that player can play. I want to build dynamic table. If user want to play 3 or 4 songs from 5, he can just check boxes next to that songs and it will built new (thats what I mean by new) table with just as many songs as he wants.

Comment: If you want to remember what songs a user wants to play, then you have to create a new table (and then you will need to modify that list with the respective queries to update the table). 
But I think it's easiest just ask for what songs he wants (fill a simple array) and then passed it to the player...

Comment: I don't need to remember that, just to send those selected songs to player. It could be done every time he logged in. It's a thing that has to be done once. If you can provide my some script or example, I would be very grateful to you...

Comment: how the player receives songs now?

Comment: This is java script code:

initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));
 
function initAudio(element){
 var song = element.attr('song');
    var title = element.text();
    var cover = element.attr('cover');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');

 //Create a New Audio Object
 audio = new Audio('media/' + song);
 
 if(!audio.currentTime){
  $('#duration').html('0.00');
 }

 $('#audio-player .title').text(title);
    $('#audio-player .artist').text(artist);

Comment: You want to fetch, from the database, information about the selected songs; and then, iterating over that resultset, dynamically produce the desired HTML.  What isn't clear is with exactly which bit of this you are stuck: fetching song information from the database; filtering datasets; using the selected songs as the data filter; iterating a resultset; or producing HTML dynamically?

Comment: The only thing that I know right now is how to fetch songs info from database. I don't know how to choose songs user wants to play and how to use those data to produce HTML dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

First, I used a list instead of table. Then, I made a table with just a name of the song (name.mp3), which is automatically post into database when uploading songs.Song and cover

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo  '<li song="', $row["name"], '" cover="', $row["cover"], '">', $row['name'] , '</li>';


} 
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Part with a user selecting songs is beyond my knowledge for now, but this is ok and working fine.